# Windows 10: Dim the brightness of a laptop below the system minimum?

Tags: windows-10, laptop

As an Android user and tweaker, I go above and beyond to achieve a level of personalization that I would like on my handset. One of the things that have very high priority to me is the minimum display brightness, because sometimes you just *need* to work at night or in dark places. On Android, if you have root, doing this is a matter of editing a single file (or installing an app, or Xposed module, to do the editing for you). On my Windows laptop, however, there seems to be no solution available. I understand why this isn't possible on a desktop (HDMI/DVI/VGA don't have any pins to control brightness), but it seems to me that, much like with an Android-powered machine, it should be possible on a Windows laptop as well.

I know there are dozens of questions like this out there but I don't think any single one of them answers the question. They all recommend either physical screen filters, *or* some software (f.lux/Dimmer etc.) that puts a *software overlay* over what you're doing on the screen that makes it seem like the display brightness is lower, but instead it's just an unhealthy amount of grey/red mixed into what's really supposed to be displayed[1].

If it isn't possible, why not? Is it a Windows limitation? A driver one? And if so, how come the Android OS has a simple workaround to this (albeit one that might damage the display)? Are there any other OSs out there that I could install on my laptop that provide this setting, either by default or through a "hack"?

[1]
If anything, I'd expect these programs to take color away rather than add it. Again, Android has a beautiful solution both in the form of kernel-controlled screen color calibration (KCAL) as well as CF.Lumen, an app that can, if so configured, make the device only display the red color channel (essentially forcing the display into black-and-red mode).

Comment: "make the device only display the red color channel" f.lux will do that, it's called darkroom mode. Combine that with minimum screen brightness and my screen is so dark as to be useless.

Comment: All it does for me is dim the display by overlaying a grey filter over the display contents. The same effect as can be achieved using Alt and PgDn.

Comment: I get red foreground on a black background. I can't show you a screenshot as the screenshot ignores the darkroom mode.

Comment: I took three screenshots, one with and one without f.lux's darkroom mode, and one with the Alt+PgDn setting. Both options have the same effect on my laptop, i.e. a grey overlay that is visible when switching between screengrabs.

Comment: Here's an example of what darkroom mode looks like on my laptop (not my screenshot) https://dukeofmedway.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/darkroommode.jpg

Comment: That would at least be semi-useful. Sadly though, it does not work for me, *and* it still leaves open a huge problem for me, which is the panel backlight.

Comment: I don't think I've anything else to add.